# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a problem sending a message to kafka using spring boot. This was working but I had to create another microservice just to insert the json object, I also changed my entities after that through postman it gives me the following error:

Ah I am using ModelMapper to serialize.

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize
> data [com.example.usercreate.dto.AddressUserDto@558d6cd1] for topic
> [quickstart-events]

First I will show my producer below my structure

My class UserCommandServiceImpl:

```
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public void createKfaka(Object object) 
    {
        logger.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", object.toString()));
        this.kafkaTemplate.send("quickstart-events", object);

    }

   @Override
    public String createItem(RequestPost request) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setCelular(request.getUser().getCelular());
            user.setCpf(request.getUser().getCpf());
            user.setCreatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            user.setEmail(request.getUser().getEmail());
            user.setNome(request.getUser().getNome());
            user.setSenha(request.getUser().getSenha());
            user.setTelefone(request.getUser().getTelefone());

            Address address = new Address();
            address.setBairro(request.getAddress().getBairro());
            address.setCidade(request.getAddress().getCidade());
            address.setComplemento(request.getAddress().getComplemento());
            address.setEndereco(request.getAddress().getEndereco());
            address.setNumero(request.getAddress().getNumero());
            address.setUser_id(user);
            user.setAddress(address);
            
            userRepository.save(user); 
            addressRepository.save(address);                       
            
            AddressUserDto dto= modelMapper.map(address, AddressUserDto.class);
            //This will add additional values to the dto.
            modelMapper.map(user, dto);
            

            this.createKfaka(dto);   
            return "Cadastrado com sucesso!";    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Email já existe! "+e;
        }

    }
```

My class Address:

```
Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("address_id")
    private Long id;


    @JsonProperty("address_endereco")
    private String endereco;


    @JsonProperty("address_bairro")
    private String bairro;


    @JsonProperty("address_numero")
    private String numero;


    @JsonProperty("address_complemento")
    private String complemento;


    @JsonProperty("address_cidade")
    private String cidade;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user_id;

}
```

My class user

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("user_nome")
    private String nome;

    @JsonProperty("user_email")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;


    @JsonProperty("user_cpf")
    private String cpf;


    @JsonProperty("user_telefone")
    private String telefone;


    @JsonProperty("user_celular")
    private String celular;


    @JsonProperty("user_senha")
    private String senha;


    @Column(name="createdAt", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonProperty("user_createdAt")
    private Date createdAt;


    @Column(name="updateAt", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonProperty("user_updateAt")
    private Date updateAt;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
    /*Person p1 = new Person("Tom", "Smith");
    p1.setId(1L);
    p1.setStartDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); */
}
```

My class AddressUserDto

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class AddressUserDto {
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("address_endereco")
    private String endereco;


    @JsonProperty("address_bairro")
    private String bairro;  


    @JsonProperty("address_numero")
    private String numero;
  

    @JsonProperty("address_complemento")
    private String complemento; 

 
    @JsonProperty("address_cidade")
    private String cidade;


    @JsonProperty("user_nome")
    private String nome;

   
    @JsonProperty("user_email")
    private String email;

  
    @JsonProperty("user_cpf")
    private String cpf;
 

  
    @JsonProperty("user_telefone")
    private String telefone;

 
    @JsonProperty("user_celular")
    private String celular;


    @JsonProperty("user_createdAt")
    private Date createdAt;

 

    @JsonProperty("user_updateAt")
    private Date updateAt;


    @JsonProperty("address_id")
    private Address address;

 
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
#spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Now my consumer follows the structure below

My class public class UserCommandInsertKafka

```
@Service
public class UserCommandInsertKafka implements UserCommandInsetKafkaService{
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserCommandInsertKafka.class);

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = "quickstart-events" , groupId = "group-id")
    public void consume(String message) 
    {
        logger.info(String.format("Message recieved -> %s", message));
        mongoTemplate.insert(message, "user");
        
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
#spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
#spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group-id
```

My Log:

```
ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

2022-11-22 22:02:03.097  INFO 8825 --- [nio-8764-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2022-11-22 22:02:03.122  INFO 8825 --- [nio-8764-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.2
2022-11-22 22:02:03.122  INFO 8825 --- [nio-8764-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: f8c67dc3ae0a3265
2022-11-22 22:02:03.122  INFO 8825 --- [nio-8764-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1669165323121
2022-11-22 22:02:03.308  INFO 8825 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition user-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to e2Cs_WMmQcW2OW-WhHMAHQ
2022-11-22 22:02:03.310  INFO 8825 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: XyE7iReFSe-z0ahzdolvWw
2022-11-22 22:02:03.325  INFO 8825 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 1000 with epoch 0
```

Can anyone find any errors? I'm grateful for the help